# SendGrid NodeJS - Client.request() is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, sendgrid

I am trying to create a user then add them to a list via the sendgrid api but I keep getting an error saying Client.request is not a function but clearly it is a function.

```
function createNewUser(list: number) {
    return Client.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/v3/contactdb/recipients',
      body: JSON.stringify([
        {
          email: format.email,
          first_name: format.name.split(' ')[0] || '',
          last_name: format.name.split(' ')[1] || ''
        }
      ])
    })
      .then(newUsers => {
        const ids = (<any>newUsers).persisted_recipients;
        return ids.forEach(async user => {
          console.log(list, user);
          Client.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `/v3/contactdb/lists/%7B${list}%7D/recipients/%7B${
              user.id
            }%7D`,
            body: 'null'
          })
            .then(success => {
              console.log(`${user.id} as been added to ${list}`);
              return res.status(200).send('OK');
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              return res.status(500).send(err);
            });
        });
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I got stuck with the same problem and after putting half an hour into it, I got to know that I was making a silly mistake and maybe, this can help you.

The way you are declaring a client is very important and may be as I was in a hurry, I did a silly mistake in declaring & require the variable.

```
const client = require('@sendgrid/mail');
```

It should be, const client = require('@sendgrid/client)

[Please have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Jw3.png)[image]

Comment: You shouldn't put your keys in an image. I assume (hope) you have revoked these.